# How to only get value from data.frame in R?

Tags: r, math, dataframe

i am trying to calculate the probabilities of 4 dices being thrown in R. I am nearly finished, i just want to know how i could possibly access ONLY the value in a specific row of my test1 dataframe? If i write rowSums(test1[1,]) it gives me both the index AND the sum, but i only want to access the sum to be able to store how many possibilities there are to get i.e. a 4 with 4 dices etc.

Here´s the important place of the code.

```
wurf1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
wurf2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
wurf3 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
wurf4 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
test1 <- data.frame(expand.grid(wurf1, wurf2, wurf3, wurf4))
rowSums(test1[1,]) #this gives me:
1
4 #because the sum of the values in index 1 = 4
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: The '1' is only the name of the element. `unname(rowSums(test1[1,]))`

Comment: Do you mean `rowSums(test1)[1]`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes i exactly meant that. Thanlk you very much!